# i want get value react promise

Tags: javascript, promise

how do i can work response back-end server?
or get valuse after pending.... how can waiting?

```
api_get()
    .then(function (response) {
         console.log("after response : ", response);
         // after response : undefined
         // How do i get value?
    })
```

```
const api_get = () => {
    axios.get(url)
        .then(function(response){
            console.log("after api : ", response.data)
            return response
        })
```

[image]

Comment: api_get doesn't actually return the promise chain.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `then` you have to return a promise. And your `api_get` function is not returning anything, just add `return` before your `axios.get`

Change your function to :

```
const api_get = () => {
    return axios.get(url)
        .then(function(response){
            console.log("after api : ", response.data)
            return response
        })
```

Answer (score -1):

you should use **axios** which is a package to connect with **backend server** and make the operations of *(GET,POST,DELETE, UPDATE)* in the frontend .
to install it :-

```
npm i axios --g
```